# Who filmed the Apollo 11 trans-lunar injection?

Tags: apollo-11

In the recent [Apollo 11 documentary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8760684/) we're shown footage of the mission undertaking a '[trans-lunar injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-lunar_injection)' burn after having conducted two orbits of the Earth.

Who was filming this sequence?

[image]

Comment: [According to this article](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/08/movies/apollo11-documentary.html), the film may actually be of Apollo 8 rather than Apollo 11, but I was unable to find any further information on the source. As the TLI burn lasted 6 minutes this may be a collection of still frames condensed to a couple of seconds rather than continuous movie film.

Comment: "*During the moments showing the translunar injection maneuver — the propulsive push that sent Apollo 11 toward the moon — Miller used a shot from Apollo 8. He hopes to document these liberties and other aspects of the filmmaking process in a production journal.*" - Interesting. So where was *that* filmed from? :-)

Comment: I'd guess Hawaii, but beyond that I've got nothing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The "TLI burn" was filmed by the crew of Apollo 9 - an Earth-orbit test of the lunar module. As explained in Scott Manley's video on Youtube, [How Did The Apollo 11 Documentary Get Film Of The Upper Stage Ignition?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=780SAiciNbU), a fully-fueled Saturn V was required to launch Apollo 9. Since the lunar module was extracted before a "TLI burn", the third stage still had lots of fuel and oxidizer. The mission design was to send the third stage into a higher orbit (and eventually heliocentric) in order to get the stage away from the crew, just in case the left over propellants decided to explode.

Comment: So it's not Apollo 11? That's disappointing.